# <Socket.io Nodejs> How to send message to a specific client

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

Let me explain my system

I have a door lock which can report status to user through a server which I use socket.io, mlab database and nodejs to implement

User can receive status report through an android phone

When someone open the door without permission, I can immediately send warning to user's phone, the problem I got here is that I dont know how to send message received from the lock (client) to user's phone (another client)

User is not always connect to server so the socketid of user's phone can always change, I found this answer **io.to(socket#id).emit('hey')** but according to document, this will send message to every socket except the socket#id

One more thing I dont know is how the server can know which lock device belong to which android phone so that it can send the warning exactly

I would really appreciate If someone can help me with my problem, this is my final project at university

Sorry if my english make you angry, I am not a native english speaker

Comment: "One more thing I dont know is how the server can know which lock device belong to which android phone so that it can send the warning exactly" for this your can map Android device UID with the lock id to identify the lock and android phone

Comment: So I have to map UID of android device with lock id then map socketid with android device UID when it connects to server. Is my understanding correct? Then my question turn to how can I send data to a specific socketid (which stand for an android device)

Comment: Okay, what you want to achieve is an 'alert_system' if some unauthorised person access the lock you need to inform the actual user. Now how can this be simulated leaving aside the implementation technology. First you need to register the lock with the user's mobile phone how can this be done simply by mapping the two unquie_id of the device here its android_uid and lock_id. now second part how to send the intrusion notification. using socket.io you can emit() message to server and than your server will emit() message to the actual device. hope you got the essence of what i am trying to say !

Comment: "Then my question turn to how can I send data to a specific socketid (which stand for an android device)"  --- for this keep in mind when you make a socket connection to server from lock_client you need to send the server the lock_id at 'onConnect' event then at server you can easily find the mapped android_uid for the lock and send the alert to the phone. hope u understand !

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand the procedure to make this happen. Can you show me how to send data to a specific socket with socketio in nodejs

Comment: I am not sure if using sockets is the best way here. Because as you said, the user needs to be connected. If the user is connected (as it was mentioned you would need to save which socketId is which user), you can send a message to a specific socketId with this:

io.sockets.connected[socketid].emit(eventname, data);

Otherwise, if the user is not connected, then I would also think about sending a text message (maybe with twilio) or a push notification https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjPqoiZSQ3wIVQqWaCh1N9QhYEAAYASAAEgKJ_fD_BwE

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know about FCM and as I searched on Google, implement it on android is more efficiently then using socketio in order to deal with my requirement, but I only have about 20 days to finish my project  and learning some quiite new thing seem impossible for me. My project is for demo only so I think socket is enough for me